# On drag and drop element to div, add an id name to url

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I didn't knew how to start working on it so I planned to ask first here.
I want to create something where you would have a list of things and you could drop it to one container div. After dropping it there it would add for example name of item's id into url, so that users could share their things with another by sharing the link. Is it possible to do with jquery?

If yes, how? :C

@edit
this is what I have so far.
Dragin and dropping from one div to another

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".merchandiser_image").draggable({ cursor: "crosshair", revert: "invalid" });
$(".selected_item").droppable({
    accept: ".merchandiser_image",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        console.log("drop");

        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(dropped).detach().css({ top: 0, left: 0 }).appendTo(droppedOn);


    },
    over: function (event, elem) {

        console.log("over");
    }
                ,
    out: function (event, elem) {

    }
});
$(".selected_item").sortable();

$(".klatka").droppable({
    accept: ".merchandiser_image", drop: function (event, ui) {
        console.log("drop");

        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(dropped).detach().css({ top: 0, left: 0 }).appendTo(droppedOn);


    }
});
```

});

Comment: Hi. Your question contains multiple questions: being able to drag and drop items, changing the URL, extracting IDs from the URL in order to add the items to the container when a URL was shared. Break things down to small problems, try to solve them, and if you get stuck, come back here with some code so we can help you. (BTW, yes, it's completely achievable with JS, and jQuery will make it easy to handle the drag and drop part)

Comment: @blex edited my post, not sure if it is any helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have everything set up for the drag and drop part. I have not tested it, but you might want to give this a try:

**Part 1** - Update the ID list in the URL when items are moved around.

In both of your `drop` functions, you can call a function to update the URL:

```
drop: function (event, ui) {
    // ...
    updateURL();
},
```

Then, write this function:

```
function updateURL(){
    // Get all selected items
    var items = $('.selected_item .merchandiser_image'),
        id_list = [];
    // Gather their IDs into an Array
    for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){ id_list.push( items[i].id ); }
    // Insert a hash in the URL, with the IDs, comma separated
    window.location.hash = id_list.join(',');
}
```

**Part 2** - Read the list in the URL on page load, and place the items in their correct spot.

Anywhere inside your `$(document).ready()`, call this function:

```
updateListFromURL();
```

And declare it:

```
function updateListFromURL(){
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if(hash){
        // replace `,` with `,#` to get a list of ID CSS selectors
        var list_of_ids = hash.split(',').join(',#');
        // Append them to your list of selected items
        $(list_of_ids).appendTo(".selected_item");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was googling for few hours but couldn't really find any article about it. It gave me now an idea how to do that :3